# Why didn't I get the Electorate badge?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges, votes

Below is my vote summary

[image]

I did not see any reason *not* to get this badge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text says:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on
>   questions.

You only voted on 279 questions.

You will get the badege when:

- you voted on 600 questions
- and at least 25% of all your votes were on questions

Comment: @iandotkelly It literally means question - the question a user asks. and not the question (with answers) as a whole.

Comment: I retract my dumb comment them :-)

Comment: could you please provide some more explanation. Do we need to vote on 600 different questions, that means upvotes on 2 or 3 answers of a question will be counted just as 1.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj a "post" contains of 2 things. ONE question (i.e.) the question here about this badge (first thing on the page) and several answers (like mine). You need to vote 600 times for the question itself not an answer. Upvotes on answers will not count for this badge (only for the ratio of questions/answers).

Comment: ***Upvotes on answers will not count for this badge***. then what it means *25% or more on questions*. what else 75% could be.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I meant votes on answers do not count for the 600, just for the ratio (as stated in the brackets)